# How do I convert Vue JS templates to pure HTML?

Tags: html, wordpress, vue.js, advanced-custom-fields, nuxt.js

I have a WordPress site that outputs its content in the form of modules based on Advanced Custom Fields fields via the Rest API to a Vue.js front-end, also using Nuxt.

I've been asked to convert this to a standard WP theme, doing away with Vue to make it a regular WordPress theme.

I have access to all the Vue files, the whole codebase in fact, but is there any 'quick' way of converting these templates to regular HTML without building the whole thing again from scratch?

If I view page source it outputs the scripts that build the page rather than the HTML I need, so if I copy this it doesn't work because Vue/Nuxt are missing.

Answer (score 2):

As you say you're using Nuxt you could explore the [Nuxt Generate](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-) command. Generate won't render any [dynamic routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes), you may not be using these, but if you are perhaps you could bake in one example of the text content, and convert your dynamic routes/templates before running Generate.

- https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-
- https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/

---

**Second very dirty suggestion:**

*I think this is a poor suggestion on my part but perhaps it will help…*

In Chrome:

If you happen to be choosing "View page source" you will see the HTML before JS [Vue] has acted upon it.

If, instead, you choose "Inspect" (open the dev tools Elements view) you will see the HTML after Vue has done it's thing to create the final HTML. You could copy this instead. Right click on the `<html>` element and select *Copy > Copy outerHTML*.

*Unfortunately, the resulting HTML will probably include lots of `data-v-xxxxxxxx` attributes and swaths of the CSS may reference these. And you'll likely have to go through page-by-page.*